# Prevent div from highlighting on key press

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've add a keydown event handler to some divs, allowing the user to shift them through a list using arrow keys.

On pressing an arrow key, the div's border changes to a blue colour.
[image]

How do I prevent this?

Comment: That's because the focus style. We don't know which widget is that, if the style comes from CSS or directly from the SO. Please, create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The first rule is "pretend that you talk to a busy colleague" so add the more data that you can to reproduce it.

Comment: You should only remove the border highlight if you don't care about accessibility. Some of your users might have bad eyesight, the border for whichever input is active helps them see where the focus is. Only remove that if you're sure that won't matter in your app's use case

Comment: Thanks everybody. I should've dug a bit deeper before. Managed to resolve it.

Comment: @Jayce444 I added my own custom selection appearance, so I wanted to remove the default selection provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in css `outline:none;` for `input`